# Rails callbacks, observers, models, and where to put methods and logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, models, observers

I'm working on an app at work. Basic stuff, user signs up (with an associated organization).

Initially I started off with a simple controller -

```
# Need to check if organization exists already; deny user creation if it does 
if @organization.save
  @user.save
  redirect_to user_dashboard_path...
```

I soon found myself in a callback soup:

After the organization is validated, we save the user.
When the organization is created, I create another two models, EmailTemplate and PassTemplate (an organization has_one :email_template, has_one :pass_template)

```
  after_create :init_company, :init_email_template, :init_pass_template, :init_form
```

Each of those callbacks generally calls method on the model, something like:

```
def init_email_template
  self.email_template.create_with_defaults
end
```

Initially I thought this was quite clever - doing so much behind the scenes, but I've been reading Code Complete by Steve McConnell, and feel this is not simple at all. If I didn't know what was happening already, There's no hint that any time an organization is created it creates 3 associated objects (and some of those objects in turn initialize children objects).

It seems like a bad programming practice, as it obfuscates what's going on.

I thought about moving all of those initalizations to the controller, as an organization is only ever created once:

```
class OrganizationsController < AC
  ...
  def create
    if @organization.save
       @organization.create_user
       @organization.create_email_template
       @organization.create_pass_template
  end
```

That seems like cleaner code, and much easier to follow.

**Question 1**
**Are there better solutions, or best practices for handling creating associated objects upon creation of the hub object that I'm unaware of?**

Side note - I would have to rewrite a bunch of tests that assume that associations are automatically created via callbacks - I'm okay with that if it's better, easier to understand code.

**Question 2**
**What about a similar situation with after_save callbacks?**

I have a customer model that checks to see if it has an associated user_account after creation, and if not, creates it. It also creates a Tag model for that user_account once we've created the user_account

```
class Customer < AR
  after_create :find_or_create_user_account

  def find_or_create_user_account
     if !self.user_account_exists?
        #create the user
     end
     Tag.create(:user_id => self.user_account.id)         
  end
end
```

Somewhat simplified, but again, I believe it's not particularly good programming. For one, I'm putting logic to create two different models in a third model. Seems sloppy and again the principle of separating logic. Secondly, the method name does not fully describe what it's doing. Perhaps find_or_create_user_account_and_tag would be a better name, but it also goes against the principle of having the method do one thing- keeping it simple.

After reading about observers and services, my world was thrown for a bit of a loop.

A few months ago I put everything in controllers. It was impossible to test well (which was fine because I didn't test). Now I have skinny controllers, but my models are obese and, I think, unhealthy (not clear, not obvious, harder to read and decipher for another programmer/myself in a few months).

**Overall I'm just wondering if there are some good guides, information, or best practices on separation of logic, avoiding callback soup, and where to different sorts of code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not the following?

```
after_create :init_associated_objects

def init_associated_objects
  init_company
  init_email_template
  init_pass_template
  init_form
end
```

My interpretation with "a method should do one thing" isn't strict and that I usually have a method that calls other method (much like the one above). At the end of the day, it's a divide and conquer strategy.

Sometimes I create utility POROs (plain old ruby objects) when it doesn't make sense to have an AR model but a group of functionalities is a class' responsibility. Reports, for instance, are not AR-backed models but it's easier when a report that needs to call multiple models is just instantiated once where the reporting period start and end are instance variables.

A rule of thumb that I follow: if I instantiate the models outside of the whole MVC stack (e.g. Rails console), the things that I expect to happen should stay inside the model.

I don't claim best practices but these have worked for me so far. I'm sure other people would have a better idea on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm researching a bit, looking through books and checking out railscasts, but this seems like a mix between a philosophical issue and a best practices one.